# Why text object can't align to Y axis accurately?

Tags: text-object, units

i am new to Blender, i certainly set Text Object Alignment in Left Horizontal way [image: demo]

and set object's X location to 0

[image]

However , the Text Object looks like this ,The left side of "P" character doesn't align exactly to 0 X location , though with its axis align to 0 location

[image]

Here is what i want , i want the Text object 's left side 100% accurately align to 0 X location every time i input 0 X location rather than manually adjust it to 0 X location

[image: What i want]

Thanks if you have any ideas , and Python adjustment method can be also acceptable to me !

Comment: Hello :). This question keeps popping up as unanswered. Please mark one of the answers as accepted **✓**, or post your own solution. Just to keep the site nice and tidy. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your location is based upon you origin (little orange dot)

[image]

If this is offset from your geometry then you will have problems in setting the exact location through this method. Also with text the origin will be the same location, but per character/font/style you may need it to be in a different location. There are some other nuances for example, here the default Bfont drops the lower case characters under the origin.

[image]

So you can set it up (by adjusting your origin), but this will *not be automatically applied to each new text object*.

So in your specific example (where you have converted the text to a mesh) adjust the origin to the lower left of the `P` and it should just go to the world origin if you set the transform to X=0, Y=0. NB Moving Origins is easy now in object mode, press Options and select Origins and then you can simply move the origin of the object. I would recommend doing this by snapping to vertex.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature (not a bug) of the font.
It's usually desired for legibility and not very noticeable for regular-sized text.

You can adjust the alignment by changing the *Offset X* value

[image]

Comment: But it also means  manually adjustment, different character will have different offset in order to align Y axis , i want it to automatically align to Y axis for all characters..

Comment: Hello :). This cannot be done. The font itself has those gaps, you'll have to do it manually. You can convert it to mesh and just snap it, but still by hand.

Comment: well,i can check if it has intersection to specific mesh and then adjust it step by step..